# Knowing how many times an item is clicked in listview in android

Tags: android, listview

Is there any way to find whether an item in a ListView is clicked for the first time in Android?

Comment: use setOnItemClickListener() to listen to the clicks on the list view item, then use sharepreferences to save your value. The next time you click you will have the sharepreferences value and check it if its true or false.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: please post why need that, I am sure there will be a better solution to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an arraylist with false for how many items in your listView, then try the following

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(arrayList.get(position) == false){ //Make sure you initialize your arraylist with false values (same amount as listView size)
            arrayList.set(position, true); //set true to an arrayList in the same index of the listView that was pressed
        }else{
            //Has been clicked before, do something
        }


        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                                                    long arg3) {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        count = map.get(your_listview_value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    map.put(your_listview_value, (count + 1));
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                             String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

To know about the basic functionality of list view , [Check this](http://simplestandroidtutorial.blogspot.in/2015/06/this-is-simplest-android-example-for.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to, you could include this info to the model wrapper, for example if you display list of Items, so you will have wrapper:

```
class ItemWrapper {
    Item mItem;
    boolean mIsClicked;
}
```

In this case when you click on your item you could get info about if this item was already clicked.

If you need for example list of Checkable items (list of checkboxes) it's the right way to do, because this item is a part of your logic, you could definitely answer if you item is checked.